# How to catch assertion error in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, try-catch

When using `try/catch` block with expect, if expect fails, error won't be caught. Is there any way to catch assertion error in javascript? Code sample:

```js
try {
  expect(2).toBe(3);
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

Comment: The error will be caught. What's wrong?

Comment: The error isn't caught because it's not a JavaScript error, it's a "design error". My question is: *why* do you want to "catch" the failed test?

Comment: Think of `try/catch` as the equivalent of telling the test runner: *"I know there's something wrong but don't worry, I can handle it. Keep going as nothing happened"*.

Comment: The idea is that whenever expect fails with some message (e.g. Expected 2 to be 3.), same message is logged into log file. I was wondering can I use try/catch for that or there is some other way.

Comment: IIRC there's a way to specify custom messages for your failed assertions. Check the docs. Otherwise in that case, try/catch is a viable way to do what you want albeit a little clumsy. If you're still hellbent on using `try/catch` the solution is probably to `throw "My Custom Error Message"` in `catch`.

Comment: My use-case is retrying a flaky assertion

Answer (score 0):

You can make a [custom matcher](https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/custom_matcher).

E.g.

```js
const customMatchers = {
  toBeWithThrow(matchersUtil) {
    return {
      compare: function (actual, expected) {
        const result = {};
        result.pass = matchersUtil.equals(actual, expected);
        if (result.pass) {
          result.message = 'Expected ' + actual + ' to be ' + expected;
        } else {
          throw new Error('Expected ' + actual + ' to be ' + expected);
        }
        return result;
      },
    };
  },
};

describe('54601177', () => {
  beforeEach(function () {
    jasmine.addMatchers(customMatchers);
  });
  it('should pass', () => {
    expect(2).toBeWithThrow(2);
  });
  it('should pass too', () => {
    try {
      expect(2).toBeWithThrow(3);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  });
});
```

test result:

```
Executing 2 defined specs...
Running in random order... (seed: 09363)

Test Suites & Specs:

1. 54601177
⠋    should pass tooError: Expected 2 to be 3
    at compare (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jasmine-examples/src/stackoverflow/54601177/index.test.js:10:17)
    at Expector.compare (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jasmine-examples/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:3969:27)
    at Expectation.toBeWithThrow (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jasmine-examples/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:3659:34)
    at UserContext.<anonymous> (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jasmine-examples/src/stackoverflow/54601177/index.test.js:27:17)
    at QueueRunner.attempt (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jasmine-examples/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:7063:44)
    at QueueRunner.run (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jasmine-examples/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:7104:25)
    at runNext (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jasmine-examples/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:7023:18)
    at next (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jasmine-examples/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:7030:11)
    at QueueRunner.onComplete (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jasmine-examples/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:6924:9)
    at Immediate._onImmediate (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jasmine-examples/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:7120:12)
   ✔ should pass too (14ms)
   ✔ should pass (1ms)

>> Done!


Summary:

  Passed
Suites:  1 of 1
Specs:   2 of 2
Expects: 1 (0 failures)
Finished in 0.024 seconds
```